# Ember.js: Converting vanilla array into Ember array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I have an array that I'm converting to `Ember` array with `A()` as I want to use some of `Ember` array methods, like `filterBy()`, but it's not producing the result I want. What is the proper way to convert a vanilla array into an `Ember` array?

#### Ember:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Component.extend({
  movieGenreIds: computed.map('movies', function(movie, index) {
    return movie.genre_ids;
  }),

  genresNames: computed('movieGenreIds', 'allGenres', function() {
    let genresArray = A(this.get('genres')); // <--- conversion here

    this.get('movieGenreIds').forEach((movieGenreId, movieGenreIndex) => {
      console.log('MOVIE_GENRE_IDS!!!', genresArray);
      console.log('FILTERBY ID^^^', genresArray.filterBy('id', movieGenreIds.toString())); // <-- not returning desired results
    });
  }),
});
```

#### Ember route (data is from themoviedb api and `models` represent the data structure in the `json` provided):

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import RSVP from 'rsvp'

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      movies: this.store.findAll('movie'),
      genres: this.store.findAll('genre'),
    })
    .then(data => data);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first `.then(data => data);` makes literally nothing. Just remove this.

Next if you don't disable the prototype extension for Arrays you dont need to *convert* normal arrays to ember arrays. so replace this:

```
let genresArray = A(this.get('genres'));
```

with this:

```
let genresArray = this.get('genres');
```

or this in ember 3.1+:

```
let genresArray = this.genres;
```

Now an interesting question is, what is `genre_ids` on the `movie` model? I strongly *assume* its a computed property that returns an array. But some code would help.

However your dependency key for `movieGenreIds` is wrong. You probably should do this:

```
movieGenreIds: computed.map('movies.@each.genre_ids', function(movie, index) {
  return movie.genre_ids;
}),
```

However your actual problem is now probably that this will probably return an *array of arrays*. So something like this:

```
[[1,2],[3],[],[4,5]]
```

Now you do `.forEach` on it, however `movieGenreId` will now probably still be an array. Next you do `movieGenreId.toString()` (you actually do `movieGenreIds.toString()`, but I assume this is a typo, because this wouldn't make sense because you don't use `movieGenreId` inside the loop then). However doing `.toString()` on an *array* will probably not give you the desired result - an id.

And so probably your fix is to fix the `movieGenreIds` CP (the code is for ember 3.1+):

```
movieGenreIds: computed('movies.@each.genre_ids', function() {
  return this.movies
    .map(m => m.genre_ids)
    .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b]);
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Lux. `genre_ids` is an array of numbers itself. Basically what I'm trying to do is, compare each number in `genre_ids` with another array, which has objects with the corresponding number and genre name, then extract that name. But I don't know how to do it. E.g. `genre_ids: [23, 19, 98]` and `genres: [{ id: 23, name: 'Action'}, { id: 19, name: 'Comedy '}, { id: 98, name: 'Romance' }]`. Sorry my Ember skills are not top.

Comment: it's not about ember, thats just javascript. And then just do as I've written. Have you tried it? I assumed basically what you've just confirmed, so my answer should help you.

Comment: It works, Thank you! But I've posted a new question to make it clearer what I really wanna do, with regard to get the movie genre names (I should have done this first, instead): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832701/matching-genre-ids-with-genre-names-in-tmdb-with-javascript