# Matching genre ids with genre names in TMDb with JavaScript (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, themoviedb-api

I'm sure a lot of you have used the TMDb (The Movie Database) api for movies. But I'm having issues with showing the genre names for each movie displayed. I'm trying to replace each number in `genre_ids`, from **movies** api, with their corresponding `name` from **genres** api, as showing numbers to users doesn't say much! But I don't get the desired result. I'm not sure what the correct way is...

**Movie adapter**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const apiKey = 'SOME_API_KEY_HERE';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: `https://api.themoviedb.org/`,
  namespace: '3',
  pathForType() {
    return `discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${apiKey}`;
  },
});
```

**Genre adapter**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const apiKey = 'SOME_API_KEY_HERE';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: `https://api.themoviedb.org/`,
  namespace: '3',
  pathForType() {
    return `genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`;
  },
});
```

**Movie serializer**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = { movies: payload.results };
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

**Genre serializer**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = { genres: payload.genres };
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

**Movie model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, hasMany } = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  vote_count: attr('number'),
  video: attr('boolean'),
  vote_average: attr('number'),
  title: attr('string'),
  popularity: attr('number'),
  poster_path: attr('string'),
  original_language: attr('string'),
  original_title: attr('string'),
  genre_ids: attr(),
  backdrop_path: attr('string'),
  adult: attr('boolean'),
  overview: attr('string'),
  release_date: attr('date'),
});
```

**Genre model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

**Route**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import RSVP from 'rsvp'

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      movies: this.store.findAll('movie'),
      genres: this.store.findAll('genre'),
    });
  },
});
```

**Movie-listing Component**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  movieGenreIds: computed('movies.@each.genre_ids', function() {
    return this.movies.map(movie => movie.genre_ids).reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b]);
  }),

  genresNames: computed('movieGenreIds', 'genres', 'movies', function() {
    let names = [];

    this.genres.map((genre) => {
      this.movieGenreIds.forEach(movieGenreId => {

        if (parseInt(genre.id) === movieGenreId) {
          names.push(genre.name);
        }
      })
    })

    return names;
  }),
});
```

**Movies API** (each movie from the `results` array has this structure):

```
{
  "vote_count": 1092,
  "id":335983,
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 6.7,
  "title": "Venom",
  "popularity": 505.173,
  "poster_path": "\/2uNW4WbgBXL25BAbXGLnLqX71Sw.jpg",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Venom",
  "genre_ids": [27,878,28,53,35], // <-- I'm interested in this property
  "backdrop_path": "\/VuukZLgaCrho2Ar8Scl9HtV3yD.jpg",
  "adult": false,
  "overview": "When Eddie Brock acquires the powers of a symbiote, he will have to release his alter-ego “Venom” to save his life.",
  "release_date": "2018-10-03"
}
```

**Genres API**

```
"genres":[
  {"id":28,"name":"Action"},
  {"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},
  {"id":16,"name":"Animation"},
  {"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},
  ...
]
```

**Hbs Template** (the expected result)

```
<ul class="movie">
{{#each movies as |movie|}}
  <li>
    <h2 class="movie__title">{{movie.title}}</h2>
    <p class="movie__genre">
      genres: 
      {{#each genresNames as |genre|}}
        {{genre}} <!-- a list of genre names for this particular movie -->
      {{/each}}
    </p>
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}" alt="" class="movie__image">
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Are you going to add to each movie object property with genre names? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve (and it seems to be unnecessary to build array `movieGenreId` for this purpose)

Comment: @barbsan, thanks for replying! Basically I want to replace the numbers in `genre_ids` array into their corresponding 'name' so I can show them in the browser. Because displaying numbers doesn't say much!

Comment: Perhaps, try this: [Getting genre name corressponding to genere id and getting cast names](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/5592d15a92514124b600055f)

Comment: Sure, but I'm asking about structure of that expected result, not why are you doing this. For what I see you're creating array of all genres without information about movie ant then you're trying to create array of genres names matching that first array ids (again without movie id)

Comment: The thing is, I've tried many ways, so the above `Ember` code was just the last effort I did, which I know it's not correct. That's why I'm asking for a new way I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Do you use ember-data? Where and how do you load the data?

Comment: @Lux! Yes I'm using `ember-data` and I access the data from the `route`. I have added some `ember-data` code. The models follow the same structure as the json. Didn't wanna make the question too long as some people don't like it, so I didn't paste the models.

Comment: Please show your models and your serializer. This should be done entirely in the serializer!

Comment: @Lux! I have pasted the models and serializers as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your primary problem is that you're trying to fix something on the component layer that is better handled on the model layer.
While you *can* do that, what you actually want is a relationship from the `movie` model to the `genre` model:

```
genres: hasMany('genre'),
```

I'm not sure what your API provides 1:1 because you've not pasted the *exact* response. At some point you've mentioned a `results` array, and the genres seems to be wrapped inside a `genres` array. So if thats not 100% correct you maybe need to tweak this solution a bit.

For the start I would recommend the newer `JSONSerializer` instead of the `RESTSerializer`.

Now you need to tell ember that for the `genres` relationship it should use the ids provided in the `genre_ids` array. This can be done by [`keyForRelationship`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/normalizeResponse?anchor=keyForRelationship):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import {singularize} from 'ember-inflector';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  ...
  keyForRelationship(key, typeClass, method) {
    return `${singularize(key)}_ids`;
  },
});
```

Here I use the [`ember-inflector`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inflector) to get the singular of the relationship name (so `genres -> genre`) and then just add `_ids`. This is enough for ember to recognize the ids and then use them to provide the right model instances.

Next you can basically just loop over `genres` on your `movie` model:

```
{{#each movie.genres as |genre|}}
  {{genre.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Now you don't even need to pass the list of all genres to the controller/template. However you still need to *load* them so `ember-data` can use them. Otherwise `ember-data` would try to fetch them individually when you use them.

So your `model` hook could look like this:

```
model() {
  return RSVP.hash({
    genres: this.store.findAll('genre'),
    movies: this.store.findAll('movie'),
  }).then(x => x.movies);
}
```

[Here is a twiddle implementing this](https://ember-twiddle.com/1d5e858b082ffa7e2ea44b84feff5389?openFiles=serializers.movie.js%2C). However because I don't wanted to live-fetch the data I've created dummy adapters that return static data.

Comment: Thanks @Lux! Your answer really helped me. I've tweaked your solution and it works. Thanks for your big help!